# C++ Two Algorithms for Same Procedure Produce Different Results

Tags: c++, optimization

I have a homework assignment where, given an array of points, we must find the number of point pairs that are less than or equal to a given distance *epsilon* apart. The first algorithm I wrote gives me the correct answer, which is here:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, CHUNK) num_threads(NB_THREADS) reduction(+:counter) private(dx, dy, distance)
for (int i = 0; i < N-1; ++i)
{
  for (int j = i+1; j < N; j = ++j)
  {
    dx = (data[j].x - data[i].x);
    dy = (data[j].y - data[i].y);
    distance = (dx*dx) + (dy*dy);

    if (distance <= epsilon_squared)
    {
      ++counter;
    }
  }
}
```

The second algorithm makes use of distance from origin and trigonometry to perform the same operations. The problem is that the final result is off by a very small margin, typically between 2-4. The point array is sorted beforehand by distance from origin.

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, CHUNK) num_threads(NB_THREADS) reduction(+:counter) private(a, b, theta, distance)
for (int i = 0; i < N-1; ++i)
{
  //dfo = distance from origin
  a = data[i].dfo;
  for (int j = i+1; j < N; j = ++j)
  {
    b = data[j].dfo;
    //find angle between point a, origin, point b
    theta = acos(((data[i].x*data[j].x)+(data[i].y*data[j].y))/((sqrt(((data[i].x*data[i].x)+(data[i].y*data[i].y)))*(sqrt((data[j].x*data[j].x)+(data[j].y*data[j].y))))));
    distance = (a*a) + (b*b) - (2*a*b*(cos(theta)));

    if (distance <= epsilon_squared)
    {
      ++counter;
    } else {
      if (abs(a-b)>epsilon)
      {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**My Question:** Can the operations in the second algorithm lead to a different distance result compared to the first algorithm? I have checked the results between the first and the second, and they seem to be completely identical. If there is a difference being created, what can I do to fix this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your claim that the second algorithm performs faster. To me it looks like it would be stupendously less efficient, with calls to trig functions, two square roots and a division.

Comment: @paddy I should explain. It makes use of sorting the point array beforehand by each point's distance to origin. The assumption is that as points get further away from the origin, so too will they become further away from the point being measured against, and so the loop can break and stop checking further points. The algorithm itself is less efficient, but it is run significantly fewer times, leading to an overall speedup.

Comment: Your second algorithm has a `break`. Would that explain the difference in speed? And are you sure about that break? Does it assume that points are sorted somehow?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Yes. The points in the new algorithm are sorted, so it is able to break after a certain point under the assumption that no points beyond that will be within the distance.

Comment: Ok, with your explanation this is not really an OpenMP question, right? You're comparing two very different algorithms.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I suppose it is not an OpenMP question, removed the tag. Still would like to find out how the operations changed the result.

Comment: Why not use the original calculation though? You know it works, and you still have `x` and `y` available, so you can do the distance-squared test. For your early-out stuff, get rid of all that trig nonsense and use `abs(a-b)` but with a higher tolerance than epsilon, to account for precision errors in the dfo calculation, subtraction _etc_. You just need to ensure that your loop is greedy enough but not excessively greedy.

Comment: @paddy You are a genius... I spent the last 3 hours trying to do this trig stuff and you just solved my problem in a few seconds. Code runs beautifully now with no errors. Thank you very, very much.

Comment: Early-out stuff can be very tricky on these types of pair-wise comparisons.  If all the points were in a ring around the origin, then `dfo` would be useless, and you induce the cost of sorting.  You could sort by `x` and screen by |x1-x2| > eps, but then points arrayed in a near vertical line would render that useless.  Just sayin...  without a priori knowledge on the point distribution, you risk wasting time.

Comment: @AirSquid your example of sorting by x-coordinate is halfway towards the construction of a quad-tree. The search space can be segmented by building a point-tree (or more generally a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)). It can be partially built, reducing dimensionality when the delta falls below some threshold (_e.g._ epsilon), Dimension 0 is just a bucket. Searching nearby points in such a tree is quite efficient. The complexity of constructing the tree is similar to that of sorting. The _difficulty_ of constructing and iterating over it is of course a factor to consider.

Comment: @paddy  Agreed.  A continued journey here would end up with a k-d tree.  Perhaps the OP could extend his introductory homework assignment for extra credit!  ;)

Comment: Note that you can apply a tiling/unrolling optimization so to make the computation about twice faster. Enabling `-O3 -mavx2 -mfma` can help a lot on relatively recent processors (x2 over SSE). Btw, `j = ++j` is confusing and bug-prone.

Comment: If the points are sorted by distance from origin you should use `lower_bound` to find the first point with the right distance from the origin to maybe be near and then just iterate from there. For points far from the origin this can skip a lot of tests.